# How does WPF OpenFileDialog track directory of last opened file?

Tags: openfiledialog, working-directory

As we know WPF `OpenFileDialog` no more changes the app's working directory and `RestoreDirectory` property is "unimplemented". However, upon subsequent open, its initial directory is default to the last opened file rather than the original working directory, so this information must be stored somewhere. I wonder is it possible to get/set it from user code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 7 the recent file information is stored in the registry at this key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Comdlg32\OpenSaveMRU
```

Beneath this key are subkeys for the various file extensions (e.g., `exe`, `docx`, `py`, etc).

Now, if you want to read these values, this will get a list of all paths stored beneath the subkeys (adapted from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vcmfcatl/thread/bfd89fd3-8dc7-4661-9878-1d8a1bf62697)):

```
String mru = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU";
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(mru);
List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();

foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName);
    object value = sk.GetValue("0");
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    byte[] data = (byte[])(value);

    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, p, data.Length);

    // get number of data;
    UInt32 cidl = (UInt32)Marshal.ReadInt16(p);

    // get parent folder
    UIntPtr parentpidl = (UIntPtr)((UInt32)p);

    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(256);

    SHGetPathFromIDListW(parentpidl, path);

    Marshal.Release(p);

    filePaths.Add(path.ToString());
}
```

References:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vcmfcatl/thread/bfd89fd3-8dc7-4661-9878-1d8a1bf62697
- [Getting the last opened file in fileopen dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714310/getting-the-last-opened-file-in-fileopen-dialog-box)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/c43ddefb-1274-4ceb-9cda-c78d860b687c)

Comment: @NS.X. At this stage I don't have access to a Windows 8 machine so I'm not sure. This key appears to have existed going back to XP/2K, though it would pay to test it out on a Win 8 install to be sure.