# SaveFileDialog RestoreDirectory doesn't work properly for %temp%

Tags: c#, .net, savefiledialog

I implemented simple Windows Forms application. I am creating simple SaveFileDialog and want to restore directory when I create this object again. However it doesn't work for %temp% folder. Why is it like this? Is it some way to fix this problem? RestoreDirectory = true works for any other folder I tried.

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveDialog.FileName = "newFile";
saveDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

saveDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I think its permission issue, since temp is a system directory

Comment: Assuming it is not permission issue, maybe you could consider using absolute path? `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: what about the `InitialDirectory` have you tried that approach ? also I do not see a file path anywhere in your code.. does it save the file in the executing directory.. meaning your `"bin\debug"\` directory..? try reading some documentation and examples [MSDN SaveFileDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353487/what-does-the-filedialog-restoredirectory-property-actually-do). I think the property does something entirely different than what you want it to. You need to save `.FileName` to a global variable, then upon "creating the object again" you need to set the `.InitialDirectory` to the variable you saved. How do you intend for a `new` object to have remembered state in the first place?

Comment: I tried using InitialDirectory. However it is the property for SaveFileDialog object and it will be destroyed when this object will be destroyed. And I want to create and show new SaveFileDialog each time the user clicks the button.
File path should be saved automatically, because I set saveDialog.RestoreDirectory = true. But it doesn't work that way. I think NatarajC may be right - it may be permission issue.

Comment: It is true that SaveFileDialog is an object, that will be deleted during Garbage Collection. However setting RestoreDirectory to true should save the state as global. Read here:
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You almost certainly misinterpret what is happening.  If you don't set the InitialDirectory property then the dialog open where ever the user last navigated.  So if the first time you navigate to TEMP then the second time it will open in TEMP again.  Just because it remembered, not because the Environment.CurrentDirectory was not restored.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Ok you are correct, the RestoreDirectory property ends up saving the directory into the registry. An 8 year old thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c43ddefb-1274-4ceb-9cda-c78d860b687c/how-to-get-the-last-directory-after-open-filedialog?forum=csharpgeneral) mentions it, but on my system apparently things changed up to windows 7. I can't get it to save the %temp% directory either.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah the very person in the thread I linked.. It doesn't work on my windows 7 system. I can navigate to, for example, `C:\test` and save something, close the program, reopen the program, and it re-opens that folder. But navigating `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp`, saving something, then reopening the program just reopens `C:\test` again--or any non special folder I select, just not the temp directory that %temp% expands to.

Comment: @Hans Passant My goal is to open dialog where ever the user last navigated. You wrote "So if the first time you navigate to TEMP then the second time it will open in TEMP again.". It isn't like that, please try saving file there by yourself. When I save file to "Temp" folder - next time I open save file dialog it isn't opened in the last folder I navigated to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raghunathan S posted working solution for this problem there:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b720c00-6952-4705-a646-8f5469fd93b1/savefiledialog-restoredirectory-doesnt-work-properly-for-temp?forum=csharpgeneral